# Javascript split not recognizing middle dot

Tags: javascript, split, special-characters

I'm trying to split a string based upon the middle dot. For some reason, it's not recognizing it. I can use a "pipe" character so I know everything else is working, but not the middle dot. Do I need to escape the middle dot? If so, how?

Javascript

```
    var sTags = $(this).text();
    // alert(sTags);
    sSplitTags = sTags.split(' | ');
    // Split isn't recognizing the middot
    // var sSplitTags = sTags.split(' &middot; ');
    // var sSplitTags = sTags.split(' · ');
    // var sSplitTags = sTags.split(' &#183; ');
    alert(sSplitTags[0]);
```

HTML

```
    <div>Upscale &middot; Gadget</div>
    <div>Expensive · Widget</div>
    <div>Expensive &#183; Widget</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there supposed to be some delimiters in your code? i see `sSplitTags = sTags.split( | );`, which would be a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe try `sTags.split(' \u00B7 ')`?

Comment: jababey, you are correct. I've edited the sample, but that is not the issue. It's just an oversight on my part as I was trying different approaches. ruakh, you're solution works! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`' \267 '` Should be what you're looking for. Javascript uses an octal encoding for special characters that differs from the html/css encoding syntax.

Here's a site with a nice lookup table: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

-EDIT-

ruakh brought up this version of `' \u00B7 '` which is also just as valid. You'll notice on the page that there is a column for hex codes and for middle dot it is `B7`. In css you would write `\00B7` but in javascript we need to qualify that this is not an octal by appending the little 'u' to the front and you'd end up with `\u00B7'`.

Comment: Thank you, TheZ! You've relieved my frustration!

Comment: No problem, you can mark this as an answer if it helped you answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The code works OK when the character encoding of the document containing the JavaScript code has been properly declared. For example, it works when the code appears, as UTF-8 encoded, inside an HTML document which is UTF-8 encoded as a whole and this encoding is adequately declared. For an external JavaScript file, the HTTP headers should be used to declare the encoding. See the W3C document on character encodings: http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php